# Cursing young children in scriptures

Tags: scripture, curse, children

We come across many curses in scriptures. But, all the curses I do remember are for adults or old people.

Are there any instances in scriptures where someone cursed young children? Do curses act for them?

Comment: Chhaya's curse to Yama should fall in this category.. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm#fn_767

Comment: Ashtavakra was cursed inside the womb itself by his grandfather. Nachiketa was cursed by his father to go to Yamalok.

Comment: Please provide them as answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are some refrences regarding this in scriptures. Ashtavakra was cursed by Khagodara in womb of his mother.

> Thus insulted in the presence of his disciples, the great sage in anger cursed his child in the womb, saying, 'Because thou speakest thus even while in the womb, therefore thou shalt be crooked in eight parts of the body. The child was accordingly born crooked, and the great sage was ever after known by the name of Ashtavakra. **[Vana Parva 132]**

Kadru cursed some of her child as they didn't followed her orders.

> **But her sons, the snakes, refusing to do her bidding, she cursed them**, saying, 'During the snake-sacrifice of the wise king Janamejaya of the Pandava race, Agni shall consume you all. **[Adi Parva 20]**